# Manipulating div size using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm trying to change the size of a div to 99% of the original size in jquery.

I'm using the following code to get the width:

```
var textwidth = $('.comment-holder').css('width');
```

This outputs a value of 400px

So how can I set the width of this div to a new value, which is 99% of the original (of  400px)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier for you to use `.width()` rather than `.css('width')` as this returns a number. So something like the following should work:

```
var $e = $('.comment-holder'),
    width = $e.width();

$e.width(width * 0.99);
```

One problem with this, is that it will override css widths such as '90%' or '10em' and will therefore stop automatic scaling and re-sizing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Use .width call
newwidth=.9*textwidth;
$('.comment-holder').width(newwidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var w= $('.comment-holder').width(); //get width
w= w * 0.99 ;
$('.comment-holder').width( w); // set new width
```